# The Kitchen Faucet

Tags: faucet

The kitchen faucet is not providing hot water, basically no water on the hot water side of the faucet. The cold water works fine. The other faucets in the home is providing hot water with no problem.

I checked the shut-off value and the water is dripping from the faucet and it's hot water. Again, only a few drips.

Comment: Have you checked the shutoff valve (usually) in the cabinet under the sink?

Comment: What is the history of this problem?